# setTimeout fails to bind to "this" prototype function

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code and I want to see `"Hello, world!"` each second, but I've got `undefined` and I can't find where is my mistake.

```
function Greeting(message, delay) {
    this.message = message;
    setTimeout(this.blowUp, delay * 1000); 
}

Greeting.prototype.blowUp = function () {
    console.log(this.message);
};

new Greeting("Hello, world!", 1);
```

Comment: For future reference, this title is pretty general. If you can be a bit more specific about your code and tag it correctly, it'll help people other people with the same question find an answer better.

Comment: @J4G - I've gone ahead and renamed the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because when `setTimeout` callback is executed, it is executed with window as its context(object referred by `this` ([this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) in the function) by default.

You can pass a custom context to the callback by using [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
function Greeting(message, delay) {
  this.message = message;
  setInterval(this.blowUp.bind(this), delay * 1000); //use setInterval since you want to repeat the callback execution
}

Greeting.prototype.blowUp = function() {
  snippet.log(this.message);
};

new Greeting("Hello, world!", 1);
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Note: You will have to use setInterval instead of setTimeout() if you want to repeat the callback execution