# Cannot read property 'hello' of undefined

Tags: javascript, scope

I have two classes Foo and Bar.

And propriety of Foo called **hello**.

Bar is calling a method of Foo using a callback which uses the property **hello**.

Whenever the value of **hello** changes in Foo, the value utilized by Bar should synchronize accordingly.

But it doesn't. How can I refactor the below code to achieve this?

```js
  class Foo{
        start(){
            const bar = new Bar()
            bar.start(this.myFooCallback)
            this.hello = 'world'
        }
        myFooCallback(){
            console.log(this.hello)
        }
    }
    class Bar{
        start(cb){
            setInterval(()=>{
                cb()
            },1000)
        }
    }
    
    const foo = new Foo()
    foo.start()
```

Comment: [setTimeout fails to bind to “this” prototype function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955836) and [Pass correct “this” context to setTimeout callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130241)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) a context:

```js
  class Foo{
        start(){
            const bar = new Bar()
            bar.start(this.myFooCallback.bind(this))
            this.hello = 'world'
        }
        myFooCallback(){
            console.log(this.hello)
        }
    }
    class Bar{
        start(cb){
            setInterval(()=>{
                cb()
            },1000)
        }
    }
    
    const foo = new Foo()
    foo.start()
```

You can read more about context and function binding:

- [Function binding](https://javascript.info/bind)
- [You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)